# Canvas Image cannot be drawn in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I have a problem to understand why I cannot draw serveral images to my canvas 
I had programmed a bigger game where my routine worked but started from scratch due to I was not able to fire a bullet at once. It always only draw the 2nd instance .

How can I draw serveral images with the For-loop or do I make some mistake?
I mean at the end he draws one picture and all the rectangles but not the Images in between? Also I read a lot of preoloading but the Parent Image from which I create an instance of,  is loaded or not?

Like said it worked in the other html and I don't understand when I am able to draw the image and when not . Atm I wanted to draw 3 images but it only draws one, Though the rectangles are drawn so the for -loop is doing it job

Here is the code :

```js
function createNew() 
{
new Usership2(300,300,'green',0);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame = function() {
 return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function(f) {
   window.setTimeout(f,1e3/60);
  }
}();
     var Obj = function (x,y,sp,size){
      this.size = size;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
         this.color = sp;
     }
     var Usership = function(x,y,sp,imagenumber){
     this.depot = 10;
     this.type = 'Usership';
     this.xtype = new Obj(x,y,sp,10);
     w.objects.push(this);
     Usership.prototype.update =function (x,y) {  
     }
     Usership.prototype.render =function () {  
     ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.fillStyle = this.xtype.color;
     ctx.fillRect(this.xtype.x, this.xtype.y,this.xtype.size,this.xtype.size);
     ctx.drawImage(imgObjs[imagenumber],x,y)
     ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
     }
     }
     var Usership2 = function(x,y,sp,imagenumber){
     this.depot = 10;
     this.type = 'Usership';
     this.xtype = new Obj(x,y,sp,10);
     w.objects.push(this);
     Usership2.prototype.update =function (x,y) {  

     }
     Usership2.prototype.render =function () {  
     ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.fillStyle = this.xtype.color;
     ctx.fillRect(this.xtype.x, this.xtype.y,this.xtype.size,this.xtype.size);
     ctx.drawImage(imgObjs2[imagenumber],x,y)
     ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
     }
     }
     var World = function(){     
      this.objects = new Array();
      this.count = function(type,sp){
       var cnt = 0;    
       for(var k = 0;k<this.objects.length;k++)
       cnt++;
      return cnt;
      }
     }
     renderWorld = function(){
      var spliceArray = Array();
      ctx.beginPath();
      objcnt = w.objects.length;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fill();   
      i = 0;
      while(i < objcnt){         
         w.objects[i].update();        
      w.objects[i].render();    
      if(w.objects[i].depot < 1)
      spliceArray.push(i);           
      i++;   
      }
      for(var k = 0;k<spliceArray.length;k++)  
      {
      w.objects.splice(spliceArray[k],1);  }
               requestAnimationFrame(renderWorld);
     }
      
      canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      width = 1024,
      height = 768;
         images = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsH6n.png'];
      imgObjs = new Array(images.length);
      for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
      imgObjs[i] = new Image();
      imgObjs[i].src = images[i];
      } 
      images2 = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsH6n.png'];
      imgObjs2 = new Array(images2.length);
      for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
      imgObjs2[i] = new Image();
      imgObjs2[i].src = images2[i];
      } 
      w = new World();
      //new Usership(100,100,'green',0);
         for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
      new Usership2(i*10,i*10,'green',0);
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(renderWorld);
```

```html
<canvas style="z-index:1" width="1024" height="768" id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:50; left:10" value="Create" onCLick="createNew()">
<input type="button" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:100; left:10" value="down" onCLick="delete()">
```

Comment: Your current code when run through the code snipper throws an, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

Comment: Strange cannot find any additional <

Comment: How do you run the codesnipper?

Comment: You don't need to add <script> tags in the JS section - it is done automatically. I have submitted an edit which resolves this issue.

Comment: At the bottom of the snippet there is a 'run code snippet' button.

Comment: Ah ok its not viewable via mobile ( Safari IOS)

Comment: Tested in IOS App of Stackoverflow and there it is also not available

Comment: Have you checked whether its really not drawing multiple or positioning 3 at the same spot ?

Comment: Dont know how to check  that at the end i didnt give  the command to do it at the same Spot - thats  why i multipied it with var i so it increases each  time in the for loop . Did that to check if one over each other. I find it extremly difficult to test things in js its more a try and error

Comment: I found the error ! ctx.drawImage(imgObjs2[imagenumber],this.xtype.x,this.xtype.y)  instead of ctx.drawImage(imgObjs2[imagenumber],x,y). The prototype function . render () had no x and y values so he didn't knew where to draw the image . Was just wondering how javascript could draw the last one as though there were no values - really strange